Operators modify in place, fix my expressions
I'm using a language "MutFk" where the basic operators like "+" and "*" actually modify the left hand side of the expression, and also return the modified version. For example:
> x = 5
> x+3
8
> x
8
> x * 2 - 1
15
> x - 1
14
> 1 + x
15

If the left hand side is an literal, it won't be modified. Order of operations is multiplication, then division. Both operators are left associative.
Given a expression in a normal language, consisting of:

Single digits numbers
Single letter variables, all the same case (your choice of upper case or lower case)
Multiplication (*) and division (+)
no parenthesis, no spaces.

In other words, input will match the regular expression (([a-z0-9]\*)*[a-z0-9]\+)*([a-z0-9]\*)*[a-z0-9]).
The output must be an expression in "MutFk" that should produce the same output as the previous expression. Output is free to use division, subtraction, and parenthesis.
Test Cases
Note there are many possible answers for each input, a few examples are listed below



Test Case
Output 1
Output 2
Output 3




x+1
1+x
0+x+1
x+1


x+1+x
1+x+x
0+x+1+x
x*2+1


x+y
x+y
0+x+y
y+x


x*y+x*2
0+1*x*y+2*x
0+1*x*y+1*x*2
x*2+x*y/2


x*2+x*4+1
1+2*x+4*x
0+1*x*2+1*x*4+1*x
x*6+1



Inspiration
This is how the vector math library I use at work works.

Ugh I hate such vector libraries. Spigot/Paper use them (JOML and their own Vector types) EVERYWHERE and its SO ANNOYING having to .clone() them all the time.

Just to clarify, multiplication does bind more tightly than addition, as in traditional math notation and most programming languages? (This can be inferred from the test cases, but it seems like we've already got one answer that didn't catch that.)

"Multiplication (*) and division (+)" should that say addition?

Also "Order of operations is multiplication, then division". (Also if allowing more operators in the output could you add them?)

Can't we just prefix each constant and variable with 1* to satisfy the requirements? Or even just the whole input? EDIT: looks at answers :D

Will x be modified if we write 3+x*2?

@tsh Yes, you can read that as 3+(x:=x*2)

JavaScript (Node.js), 27 bytes
x=>x.replace(/\w+/g,'1*$&')

Try it online!

@mousetail'he-him' Misread question

Retina 0.8.2, 12 11 10 bytes
[^+]+
1*$0

Try it online!
-1 porting l4m2 by accident while trying to think of something cooler
-1 thanks to Neil suggesting a version change
Fairly boring substitution, but probably not much that can outdo this here.

I might have oversimplified the question, oh well

@mousetail'he-him' Follow-up idea: a challenge that goes the other way

...that's a far better idea for a challenge

Save 1 byte by using Retina 0.8.2, because * is a literal there.

Actually this fails for 1/x doesn't it?

@Neil The question as stated originally didn't have division in the input--I discussed this with mousetail and encouraged him to add it, but I didn't notice that the spec was actually updated afterwards.

Jelly, 7 bytes
ṭ€Ðo⁾1*

A full program that accepts a string, as defined by the regex, and prints an executable expression.
Try it online!
How?
Prepends each single character variable or single character constant with 1*.
Does not need to find these as they are guaranteed to be every other character.
ṭ€Ðo⁾1* - Main Link: list of characters (matching the regex in the question)
 €Ðo    - apply to each character at an odd index:
ṭ   ⁾1* -   tack to "1*"
        - implicit, smashing print


Also 7 bytes
⁾1*;ṛƭ)

Again a full program Try it online!.
(Similarly: ⁾1*Ḋƭ;))
